# Assign app_id to facebook after init?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My scenario is the following. I developed a Wordpress plugin that call fb.init the following way:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : WsiMyAjax.appId,
  xfbml      : false,
  version    : 'v2.0'
});
};
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/"+WsiMyAjax.locale+"/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Later in the script I just use to create a normal send dialog popup:

```
FB.ui(
        {
         method: 'send',
         link: link,
        }
```

The problem is that another plugin which I have no access and it can't be disabled or modified already called in the header the fb js like:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

When my send dialog is fired on the popup url query string the app_id is empty, so the popup fails. If the above line it's removed when the popup pops the app_id appears on the query string

Is there any way to assign app_id before calling fb.ui? 
Is there any way to prefix FB variable so it don't get overwritten by other script that don't use an appId?

Comment: 1. Why is your app_id empty? 2. What do you mean by *There is any way to assign app_id afterwards? Or use my own fb.init to avoid this issue?* - its not clear at all! What all are you doing with the Graph API in your app? I think you are unnecessarily making the things complicated here

Comment: When you call fb.ui with send method by default a new window pops. That new popup url have app_id= on the query string without a value. I will update my question to make it more clear

Comment: I edited the question. Let me know if it's more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Why are there 2 scripts? Where do you want to embed the appid? and where its coming empty? Its still not clear to me at all, but the way you are doing isn't correct for sure. May be someone else can help you out with this

Comment: Sahil if you read it again you will notice that it's a wordpress site. One plugin (mine) include the fb javascript the way Facebook recommends, the other plugin from another author don't, and it's making my script fail.